# Hide Price filter from some required category

Tags: magento, filter, navigation, price, layered

Is there any way to remove Price filter from some required category, while in other category show price filter magento 1.9.1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I have done this.

Comment: Actually this I was using the magento extension to select multiple options from the nav menu (i.e. https://github.com/manadev/manadev-layered-nav-multiple-select-for-magento ) 

So was not able to write the correct code in magento back-end 
Category -> Custom Design -> "Custom Layout Update" area

I used this code in "Custom Layout Update option" and now working fine... to hide category filter...


<reference name="mana.catalog.leftnav">
    <action method="setData">
        <instruction>hide_category</instruction>
        <value>1</value>
    </action>
</reference>

Comment: I'm glad you got a solution, but even if you had a programmatic solution it doesn't mean the question is about programming. You do need to make sure your question is explicitly about programming.